# Netsuite Connection through OAuth 1.0 Python

Tags: python, netsuite

I am trying to post a record into Netsuite and it works well with the Postman, but throwing invalid login Error with Python.

Below is the Code.

```
import requests

url = "https://5559796-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/qbc_pqr_1234"

payload="{\"aaa\":\"AN\",\"bbb\":\"OA\",\"ccc\":1,\"ddd\":false,\"eee\":114.01,\"fff\":\"OAOTWH\",\"ggg\":\"hhh\",\"hhh\":18,\"iii\":2,\"jjj\":\"2021-07-31\",\"kkk\":3257.29,\"lll\":\"Intra-Brand Stay - 3.5%\"}"
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'OAuth realm="5559796_SB1",oauth_consumer_key="xxxxx",oauth_token="abcdefgh",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",oauth_timestamp="1630905651",oauth_nonce="xxxxx",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="xxxxx"'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

And the error is :

```
{"type":"https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2","title":"Unauthorized","status":401,"o:errorDetails":[{"detail":"Invalid login attempt. For more details, see the Login Audit Trail in the NetSuite UI at Setup > Users/Roles > User Management > View Login Audit Trail.","o:errorCode":"INVALID_LOGIN"}]}
```

Also, how can I read the payload from a json file with multiple records.

Answer (score 1):

While hitting NetSuite API you need to create a **`signature`** which is responsible to establish your connection below is the code which will help you.

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import json
import requests
import base64
import time
import random
import urllib.parse

def _generateTimestamp():
    return str(int(time.time()))

def _generateNonce(length=11):
    """Generate pseudorandom number"""
    return ''.join([str(random.randint(0, 9)) for i in range(length)])

def _generateSignature(method, url, consumerKey, Nonce, currentTime, token, consumerSecret,
                       tokenSecret, offset):
    signature_method = 'HMAC-SHA256'
    version = '1.0'
    base_url = url
    encoded_url = urllib.parse.quote_plus(base_url)
    collected_string = None
    if type(offset) == int:
        collected_string = '&'.join(['oauth_consumer_key=' + consumerKey, 'oauth_nonce=' + Nonce,
                                     'oauth_signature_method=' + signature_method, 'oauth_timestamp=' + currentTime,
                                     'oauth_token=' + token, 'oauth_version=' + version, 'offset=' + str(offset)])
    else:
        collected_string = '&'.join(['oauth_consumer_key=' + consumerKey, 'oauth_nonce=' + Nonce,
                                     'oauth_signature_method=' + signature_method, 'oauth_timestamp=' + currentTime,
                                     'oauth_token=' + token, 'oauth_version=' + version])
    encoded_string = urllib.parse.quote_plus(collected_string)
    base = '&'.join([method, encoded_url, encoded_string])
    key = '&'.join([consumerSecret, tokenSecret])
    digest = hmac.new(key=str.encode(key), msg=str.encode(base), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
    signature = base64.b64encode(digest).decode()
    return urllib.parse.quote_plus(signature)

def import_customer():
    nsAccountID = "YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID"
    consumerKey = "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY"
    consumerSecret = "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
    token = "YOUR_TOKEN"
    tokenSecret = "YOUR_TOKEN_SECRET"
    base_url = "https://nsAccountID.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customer"
    Nonce = self._generateNonce(length=11)
    currentTime = self._generateTimestamp()

    signature = self._generateSignature('GET', base_url, consumerKey, Nonce, currentTime, token, consumerSecret, tokenSecret, offset)

    payload = ""
    oauth = "OAuth realm=\"" + nsAccountID + "\"," \
                                                     "oauth_consumer_key=\"" + consumerKey + "\"," \
                                                                                             "oauth_token=\"" + token + "\"," \
                                                                                                                        "oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA256\"," \
                                                                                                                        "oauth_timestamp=\"" + currentTime + "\"," \
                                                                                                                                                             "oauth_nonce=\"" + Nonce + "\"," \
                                                                                                                                                                                        "oauth_version=\"1.0\"," \
                                                                                                                                                                                        "oauth_signature=\"" + signature + "\""
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'Authorization': oauth,
        'cache-control': "no-cache",
    }
    response = requests.request("GET", base_url + '?offset=' + str(offset), data=payload, headers=headers)
    return json.loads(response.text)

print(import_customer())
```

And here you can see the example of **`import customer`**. In every API hit you need to generate signature with every required information

Comment: Something is missing in this script, I am not getting any output, Where is the function call?

Comment: Many Thanks. Looks like I could connect, but nothing is getting posted into netsuite. But I am getting Response 200

Comment: @ Adam Strauss  Any idea on why data is not getting posted?

Comment: can you please send me the link of API you are using?

Comment: are you using this link https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/APIs/REST_API_Browser/record/v1/2020.2/index.html#tag-customer

Comment: @Tessy And it would be great if you tell me why did you accept my answer then you removed it?

Comment: Not sure of the link you pasted, https://12345-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/ is the part of the url I am trying to access, I accepted your solution thinking it works, but later realized, the data was not posted.

Comment: Hey @AdamStrauss I just really want to than you for this. I've been trying to get this to work for days now and I finally foundr your reponse. IDK why it works yet, but IT DOES.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way would be to use requests_oauthlib, you can make it work with few lines and don't need to generate signature which is a bit tricky.

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
auth = OAuth1(
    client_key=CONSUMER_KEY,
    client_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
    resource_owner_key=TOKEN_ID,
    resource_owner_secret=TOKEN_SECRET,
    realm="YOUR_REALM",
    signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",
)
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
response = requests.request("GET", URL, auth=auth, headers=headers)
```

Comment: While this doesn't answer the question of how to follow Netsuite's 3 step authorization flow, this is the best answer IMO. The solution is simple and gets the job done.