# NetSuite OAuth 1.0 - Python - Extraction

Tags: python, python-3.x, netsuite, netsuite-rest-api

I am trying to geta record from Netsuite and it works well with the Postman, but throwing invalid login Error with Python.

My code as follow

```
import requests

url = "https://XXXXX.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/invoice"

payload = {}
headers = {'Authorization': 'OAuth realm="XXXX",oauth_consumer_key="XXXX",oauth_token="XXXX",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",oauth_timestamp="1684055638",oauth_nonce="Qm3LBoBxW3G",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="Qvrw5wZ0ur%2BEc3wxgx67KUsWlu%2Bhn%2FlrUpH9j%2FNADbs%3D"'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Getting below error

```
Error!
401
b'{"type":"https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2","title":"Unauthorized","status":401,"o:errorDetails":[{"detail":"Invalid login attempt.","o:errorCode":"INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT"}]}\n'
```

I am an Administrator in Netsuite and working well with Postman. It seems many got this error message in the Stackoverflow but unable to get the solution. Seems there is some issue in the signature and timestamp after seeing this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69069825/netsuite-connection-through-oauth-1-0-python) . However, unable to find a solution.

Can anyone advise me how to rectify this? Trying for a long time

Comment: Is it not the principle of OAuth that if you get a 401, you should call the Access Token URL of the service to refresh the token?

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when you have wrongly typed something. Make sure to copy past correctly all the data.
If you use the sandbox, don't forget that the account_realm is with an underscore and upper case: XXXXXXX_SB1
The account id is with a dash and lowercase: XXXXXXX-sb1

Comment: I used the correct one but still the same. Its working in Postman. My account id : 23XXXX-sb2 and account realm : 23XXXX_SB2